# How to finish ProgressDialog from onBackPressed

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I am using progress bar for showing progress. But when I'm pressing the back button it keep showing progress bar.I don't want it. how to remove it.
My code for calling Progress circle is-

```
    public void onClick(final View v) {
    ProgressCircle progressBar = new ProgressCircle();
    progressBar.start(v.getContext());
    click(v);
    if(progressBarStatus==1)
    {
        progressBar.stop();
    }
}
```

Following is the click(View) method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddFriend.this, AddFriendSend.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Following is the Progress Circle class:

```
 public class ProgressCircle {
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

public void start(Context context) {
    ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Processing...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.show();
}

public void stop() {
    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.dismiss();

    }
}
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Just make your ProgressCircle object global e.i. declare the object outside the onClick method and initialize it the object inside the method. Then in the onBackPressed method call progressBar.stop() but do remember to put a null check before it.

Comment: I have edited click(View method). Please take a look. @Tushski

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you override the onBackPressed method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    progressBar.stop();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Please take look on click() method @Fakher

Comment: explain more plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override back button in android as below -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    progressBar.stop();

}
```

- Don't forget to declare `progressBar` as class member.

Comment: Please take a look again @Kevz

Comment: @Ashu: u r starting a 'AddFriendSend' Activity. When exactly u want to dismiss the progress dialog?

Answer (score 0):

No Like this:

```
    ProgressCircle progressBar = null;

    public void onClick(final View v) {
        progressBar = new ProgressCircle();
        progressBar.start(this);
        click(v);
        if(progressBarStatus==1)
        {
            progressBar.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(progressBar!=null)
            progressBar.stop();
        else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: You doing this inside an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Change progressBar.start(v.getContext()) to progressBar.start(this)

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake-
we can do this by following code -

```
 ProgressCircle progressBar = null;

public void onClick(final View v) {
    progressBar = new ProgressCircle();
    progressBar.start(this);
    click(v);
    if(progressBarStatus==1)
    {
        progressBar.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(progressBar!=null)
        progressBar.stop();
    else
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```